# Why does the form_open not posting anything?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP and currently trying to make a Change Password script.
My change password function is in a controller called scrips.Can't quite understand why it's not posting anything at all.

This is my controller :

```
public function change_password()
{   
    $this->page_handler->member_page();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_pass','Old Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_pw','New Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_pw','Confirm Password','required|matches[new_pw]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() !=true) {
        $sql=$this->db->select("*")->from("members")->where("username", $this->session->userdata("username"))->get();

        foreach ($sql->result() as $my_info) {
            $db_password=$my_info->password;
            $db_id -$my_info->id;
        }

        if(md5($this->input->post("old_pass"))== $db_password) {    
            $fixed_pw = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post("new_pw")));
            $update=$this->db->query("UPDATE 'members' SET 'password' = '$fixed_pw' WHERE 'id'='$db_id'") or die(mysql_error());

            $this->session->set_flashdata("notification","Password has been updated!");
            redirect('home_view');
        } else {
            echo "A problem has occurred,please try again.";
            $this->load_view("home_view");    
        }    
    }        
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open('scripts/change_password') ?> 

    <input placeholder="Old Password" 
           id="old_pass" 
           value="<?php echo set_value(md5('old_pass')); ?> "
           name="old_pass" 
           class="w3-input w3-border"
           type="password" >

    <input placeholder="New Password"
           id="new_pw" 
           value="<?php echo set_value('new_pw'); ?>" 
           name="new_pw" 
           class="w3-input w3-border" 
           type="password">

    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" 
           id="conf_pw" 
           value="<?php echo set_value('conf_pw'); ?>" 
           name="conf_pw"
           class="w3-input w3-border" 
           type="password">

    <input class="w3-margin-top w3-btn w3-hover-white" 
           type="submit" 
           value="Change Password "
           style="width:100%">Change my password</button>

<?php form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: hi, where your `form_open('controller')` is?

Comment: for some reason it woudn't show up, now it shoud appear in view, it's the first line

Comment: Hey - its great that you are learning PHP and Codeigniter ! And with CI you can build anything pretty easily. But for User Auth, Login, etc - would strongly recommend you learn and use an established Library like Ion Auth. https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Comment: Did you missing your `name` attribute in the `submit input` ?

Comment: Still doesen't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is within your change_password() method, you are checking that the validator is NOT validating:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() !=true) {
    ...
}
```

Change it to:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
   ...
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: No change, it does not want to post the data from the input.

Comment: What do you get when you dump the post data? var_dump($this->input->post()); in the change_password() method, also, what do you get with var_dump(validation_errors());? put that at the end of your method.